# Erro ao tentar qualquer comando com o apt. E: Malformed entry 1 in list file..."

Tags: linux, terminal

Ao tentar utilizar qualquer comando com o apt, por exemplo: "sudo apt-get update", estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list ([option] not assignmen
```

Alguem conhece alguma forma de solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Meu inglês não é muito bom, mas ali parece estar dizendo, que tem alguma entrada mal formada no arquivo, você sabe o que tem dentro do arquivo? Qual distro usa?

Comment: Desculpa a demora, eu estava no trabalho...  tem isso dentro do arquivo; deb [arch = amd64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic / mongodb-org / 4$
    eu uso um linux mint tessa 19 cinamon

Comment: Resolvi o problema apenas comentando a linha no arquivo indicado no erro.